# TSQL Replace large block of text

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that is storing xml data in a nvarchar(max).  Here is a part of the data that is stored.

```
  <Groups />
  <Groups2 />
  <pairs>
    <p>
      <Name>AllowPeerDownload</Name>
      <Val>false</Val>
    </p>
    <p>
      <Name>AllowUserCancelScan</Name>
      <Val>false</Val>
    </p>
    <p>
      <Name>AutoCloseTimeout</Name>
      <Val>60</Val>
    </p>
    <p>
      <Name>CalculateHashes</Name>
      <Val>false</Val>
    </p>
    <p>
      <Name>DayOfMonthEnabled_0</Name>
      <Val>false</Val>
    </p>
  </pairs>
  <Default>false</Default>
```

It works for names that start with rep% but it makes the rest nulls.

```
    UPDATE AgentBehavior 
   SET BehaviorXML = ( SELECT 
        LEFT(BehaviorXML, CHARINDEX('<pairs>', BehaviorXML) +7) 
        +     '<p>
      <Name>AllowPeerDownload</Name>
      <Val>True</Val>
    </p>
    <p>
      <Name>AllowUserCancelScan</Name>
      <Val>false</Val>
    </p>
    <p>
      <Name>AutoCloseTimeout</Name>
      <Val>60</Val>
    </p>
    <p>
      <Name>CalculateHashes</Name>
      <Val>false</Val>
    </p>
    <p>
      <Name>DayOfMonthEnabled_0</Name>
      <Val>True</Val>
    </p>'
        
        + SUBSTRING(BehaviorXML, CHARINDEX('</pairs', BehaviorXML), LEN(BehaviorXML))

        FROM    AgentBehavior AB
        where AgentBehavior.name = ab.name
  and name like 'Rep%' )
```

This updates the ones that I want but it makes updates the ones that do not start with rep% to nulls.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
xAFGuy

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: If you were storing it in an `xml` column, it would be as simple as `UPDATE AgentBehavior SET BehaviorXML.modify('replace value of (/pairs)[1] with sql:variable('@myNewXml')')` It's going to be much messier with `nvarchar`

Comment: In fact it is so messy that I would probably consider dumping it all into a table variable of `(id, xml)` doing the modification with XQuery as I said, then saving it back. And I would strongly consider changing the column to `xml`.

Comment: Thanks Charlieface for the idea.  I think that is the direction I will go.  Unfortunately, it is a 3rd party database that I am unable to change the datatype.

Comment: Well @Charlieface, it was a great idea but SQL didn't like some of the characters that they were storing so I was unable to copy to an XML column.  I put together a workaround.

Comment: Then it isn't valid XML anyway. You should be using character encoding and escaping

Answer (score 0):

So I was unable to get the command working in TSQL.  I was unable to get the select to work without either updating all of the columns or getting an error that my subquery returned more than one value.  I know a little more about PowerShell than TSQL so I decided to use it instead.

This script will look for any text between 2 XML tags,  and  for this example and will replace it with the text between the 2 + signs.

```
cls 
$TableName = "TestTable"
$DBServer = "TesServer"
$DBName = "TestDB"


$AgentNames = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT top 2 [Name] FROM $DbName.dbo.$TableName where name like 'rep%' " -ServerInstance $DBServer

Foreach ($AgentName in $AgentNames) {
    $Name = $AgentName.Name

    $SQLCommand = " use $DBName
    UPDATE AgentBehaviorTestArea
       SET BehaviorXML = ( SELECT   LEFT(BehaviorXML, CHARINDEX('<pairs>', BehaviorXML) +7) 
            +     '<p>
          <Name>AllowPeerDownload</Name>
          <Val>False</Val>
        </p>
        <p>
          <Name>AllowUserCancelScan</Name>
          <Val>false</Val>
        </p>'
            
            + SUBSTRING(BehaviorXML, CHARINDEX('</pairs', BehaviorXML), LEN(BehaviorXML))

            FROM    AgentBehaviorTestArea
            WHERE name = '$Name')
            WHERE name = '$Name'
    "
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQLCommand -ServerInstance $DBServer 
}
```